# How do I make ls honour .hidden files?

Tags: ls, hidden-files

The `.hidden` file is quite convenient to hide directories, what applications use and generated themselves.

How do I treat items listed in the `.hidden` file hidden, while using `ls`?

[image: https://sh.c7.ee/5JG0W/Screenshot%20from%202020-02-19%2000-52-35.png]

Comment: By default, `ls` "hides" all files that begin with `.`

Comment: see https://sh.c7.ee/5JG0W/Screenshot%20from%202020-02-19%2000-52-35.png
I want ls to also hide items in the .hidden file

Answer (score 0):

By default, files in a .hidden file folder would not be hidden themselves: check it with `ls -l0`.

You can hide [them individually](https://osxdaily.com/2012/07/19/hide-file-mac-os-x-chflags/)

```sh
chflags hidden .hidden/foo
chflags hidden .hidden/foo
```

Check also their [Extended Attributes with `xattr`](https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/03/view-remove-extended-attributes-file-mac/) to see if they have any special attribute compared to regular files outside `.hidden`